# can I access localStorage data from android in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, cordova-plugins

I have created simple cordova project added android platform I want localStorage  value in android java class which i set in javascript

Before this I read some posts telling that to install `cordova-plugin-nativestorage` but no luck I can't read the value.

I am setting value in index.js

```
NativeStorage.setItem("username", "xyz", this.setSuccess, this.setError);

    function setSuccess(obj) {
        alert(obj);
    //   NativeStorage.getItem("reference", this.getSuccess, this.getError);
    }
    function setError(error) {
        alert(error.code);
        if (error.exception !== "")
            alert(error.exception);
    }
```

I am getting value in .java file below.

```
String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences= 
context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name= sharedpreferences.getString("username","");
```

I am getting name is **empty**

Please help.